# Материал не становится прозрачным после смены Rendering Mode из скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

```
for (int i = 0; i < castingObject.childCount; i++)
    {
     MeshRenderer rend = castingObject.GetChild(i).GetComponent<MeshRenderer();
     rend.material.SetFloat("_Mode", 2.0f);
     rend.material.color = new Color(rend.material.color.r, 
     rend.material.color.g, rend.material.color.b, 0);
     }
```

Изначально rendering Mode - Opaque. После выполнения данного куска Rendering Mode меняется на Fade и альфа в 0 уходит, но материал не прозрачный. Если ставить изначально Rendering Mode - Fade, то все работает после выполнения этого кода, но эт не очень подходит, так как объект просвечивается.

Comment: А не пробовали сам шейдер смотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще добавь и будет работать

```
 m.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
 m.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
 m.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
 m.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
 m.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
 m.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
 m.renderQueue = 3000;
```

[Источник](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1016155/standard-material-shader-ignoring-setfloat-propert.html)

p.s. Что значит, не подходит, что объект просвечивается?  Fade именно это и делает.

Comment: Да, забыл сказать, что при старте объект должен быть НЕ прозрачным, поэтому Rendering Mode - Fade не подходило. Мне нужно только в нескольких случаях эта фича. Ваш метод работает. спс!